# sequenceU returns G.M[List[G.A]] instead of expected type

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm trying to use the sequenceU function on a List of Validation objects, but I keep on getting the error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : G.M[List[G.A]]
 required: scalaz.package.ValidationNEL[com.gaiam.gcsis.ws.validation.DataError,List[com.gaiam.gcsi.entities.plan.Service]]
[ERROR]       val services: ValidationNEL[DataError, List[Service]] = valServices.sequenceU
```

I have two types here.  The DataError class is a scala class (non-case class).  The Service class is a Java class.

And here is the code where I receive this error.

```
val valServices: List[ValidationNEL[DataError, Service]] = XXX

val services: ValidationNEL[DataError, List[Service]] = valServices.sequenceU
```

Any thoughts on why I keep getting the type mismatch?  I am on 7.0.0-M7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably on a 2.9.x version of Scala. Add -Ydependent-method-types as a compiler option

Comment: This worked thanks, but what is Acal?  Did you mean Scala?  Because yes, I am on Scala 2.9.x.

Comment: OOps! sorry for the typo! thanks to @huynhjl for the correction!